# XRDP stopped working after Java 8 install

Tags: xrdp

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and XRDP was working fine. After installing Java 8 run-time XRDP stopped working. I have uninstalled Java 8. Uninstalled and purged XRDP and deleted all the config folders I know of. Reinstalled XRDP and get the same problem.

xrdp.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

I have installed 2 different desktops and tried reinstalling XRDP each time. No luck exactly the same error.

I have about 10 man hours into trying to fix this with no sign of improvement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The same issue happened to me after running `sudo apt upgrade`, before that xrdp was working properly. May be the issue is not with Java 8 but with some other update?

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me after running `sudo apt upgrade`.
The following commands fixed the issue:

```
sudo apt remove xrdp
sudo apt purge xrdp
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install xrdp
sudo systemctl enable xrdp
sudo service xrdp start
```

I think `apt autoremove` is the key command.